# Object level permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering about the right place for object level permissions. I'm using django-guardian for this with post_save hook:

```
def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
    assign_perm('view_media', self.request.user, obj)
    assign_perm('delete_media', self.request.user, obj)
```

That works fine for simple objects, but it gets problematic with linked objects. Let's take this example:

**Models**

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, name='id', db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'choices'

        permissions = (
            ('view_firstmodel', 'Can view firstmodel'),
            ('update_firstmodel', 'Can update firstmodel')
        )


class SecondModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, name='id', db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    parent_firstmodel = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel, related_name='secondmodel_objects')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'choices'

        permissions = (
            ('view_secondmodel', 'Can view secondmodel'),
            ('update_secondmodel', 'Can update secondmodel')
        )
```

**Serializers**

```
class SecondModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    parent_firstmodel = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = SecondModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent_firstmodel')


class FirstModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    secondmodel_objects = SecondModelSerializer(many=True, allow_add_remove=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FirstModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'secondmodel_objects')
```

**Views**

```
class FirstModelList(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FirstModelSerializer
    model = FirstModel

    def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
        assign_perm('view_firstmodel', self.request.user, obj)
        assign_perm('update_firstmodel', self.request.user, obj)
        assign_perm('delete_firstmodel', self.request.user, obj)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'view_firstmodel', klass=FirstModel)

class FirstModelDetail(RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = FirstModelSerializer
    model = FirstModel

    def get_queryset(self):

        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            required_permission = 'view_firstmodel'
        elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':
            required_permission = 'update_firstmodel'
        elif self.request.method == 'DELETE':
            required_permission = 'delete_firstmodel'

        return get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, required_permission, klass=FirstModel)

class SecondModelList(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SecondModelSerializer
    model = SecondModel

    def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
        assign_perm('view_secondmodel', self.request.user, obj)
        assign_perm('update_secondmodel', self.request.user, obj)
        assign_perm('delete_secondmodel', self.request.user, obj)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'view_secondmodel', klass=SecondModel)


class SecondModelDetail(RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = SecondModelSerializer
    model = SecondModel

    def get_queryset(self):

        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            required_permission = 'view_secondmodel'
        elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':
            required_permission = 'update_secondmodel'
        elif self.request.method == 'DELETE':
            required_permission = 'delete_secondmodel'

        return get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, required_permission, klass=SecondModel)
```

As it is, there is no check in the secondmodel that **parent_firstmodel** field is referencing an object on which the user has rights (let's say view permissions).

Suppose we have 2 users, each created one **firstmodel** object:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "user1 object firstmodel",
   secondmodel_objects: []
}

{
   id: 2,
   name: "user2 object firstmodel",
   secondmodel_objects: []
}
```

Now, the user 2, could very well create a secondmodel object like this:

```
{
    name: "user2 object secondmodel",
    parent_firstmodel: 1
}
```

So basically he attaches something to an object on which he has no permissions. Of course I could check for this specific case in the post method but I feel like it's not the right place. I would rather say that the right place for those check is somewhere in the serializer.

Am I missing something ? Anybody could share some experience about how to manage this properly ?

Comment: Are you using Django-Rest-Framework?

Comment: Yes. Ouch forgot to mention explicitly, sorry.